# 1 sample wilcoxon sign test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, nonparametric, scipy

I see the implementation of wilcoxon test in scipy as follows -

```
scipy.stats.wilcoxon(x, y=None, zero_method='wilcox', correction=False, alternative='two-sided', method='auto', *, axis=0, nan_policy='propagate', keepdims=False)
```

It seems that the implementation is applicable when you have two samples (x and y) or you have the difference of the samples(just specify the difference using x). I wanted to understand if I can use this implementation when I have only one sample( let's say s) and a population mean to compare against(mu). Basically can I just pass (s - mu) as the "x" parameter to the wilcoxon function and get a p value corresponding to whether sample mean is different from population mean.

P.S. - I know that wilcoxon test is for medians but my underlying distribution is symmetric so it does not matter.

Comment: The Wilcoxon signed rank test is NOT for medians. If you want to do a nonparametric test for means, why not use an ordinary permutation test of the mean?

Comment: For permutation test it is required that there be two samples. I only have one sample to test against a reference mean value. Also from what I read, there is a symmetry assumption so people use wilcoxon for mean/median testing

Comment: 1. Your assertion in the first sentence of your comment is false. Indeed the Wilcoxon signed rank test is also a  permutation test (just not of means).  Wherever you're getting your information from, it's misleading you. I would hold doubt about other things you might be getting from it. $\,$ 2. There is a symmetry assumption *under the null* ( but not required under the alternative) in both the Wilcoxon signed rank test and a permutation test of means. The sample doesn't tell you whether that assumption is reasonable, since you don't know that the null is true (it's likely strictly false)